# How can I adjust this regex to filter out "

Tags: java, html, regex, hyperlink

I got the following regex working to search for video links in a page

```
(http(s?):/)(/[^/]+)\\S+.\\.(?:avi|flv|mp4)
```

Unfortunately it does not stop at the end of the link if there is another match right behind it, for example this video link

```
<a href="http://somevideo.flv">somevideoname.avi</a>
```

would, after regex return this:

```
http://somevideo.flv">somevideoname.avi
```

How can I adjust the regex to avoid this? I would like to learn more about regex, its fascinating but so complex!

Comment: Do you want to find links only from `<a href="..">` or  also links from text content like `<span>http://someMovie.flv</span>`?

Comment: Then regex is not the right tool for this. You should use HTML parser instead like for example JSoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do something similar with JSoup parser.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
String htmlString = scanner.next();
scanner.close();

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
// or to get connect of some page use
// Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
Elements elements = doc.select("a[href]");//find all anchors with href attribute
for (Element el : elements) {
    URL url = new URL(el.attr("href"));
    if (url.getPath().matches(".*\\.(?:avi|flv|mp4)")) {
        System.out.println("url: " + url);
        //System.out.println("file: " + url.getPath());
        System.out.println("file name: "
                + new File(url.getPath()).getName());
        System.out.println("------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the groupings in your regexp.  At any rate, this one should work:

```
\\bhttps?://[^\"]+?\\.(?:avi|flv|mp4)\\b
```

Comment: This will also find `http://someMovie2.mp4` in `<a href="http://someMovie1.avi">link1</a><span>http://someMovie2.mp4</span>`

Comment: My mistake, there was a maximal match in the second group.  Completely rewrote the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to extract href attribute values then you're better off matching against the following pattern:

```
href=("|')(.*?)\.(avi|flv|mp4)\1
```

This should match "href" followed by either a double-quote or single-quote character, then capture everything up to (and including) the next character which matches the starting quote character. Then your href attribute can be extracted by

```
matcher.group(2) + "." + matcher.group(3)
```

to concatenate the file path and name with a period and then the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is greedy:

Limit its greediness [read this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
(http(s?):/)(/[^/]+?)\\S+.\\.(?:avi|flv|mp4)
```